# why is mechanize not searching this form?

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I am new to Mechanize. I am trying to search a form with the search term "TAICHI 21" but it does not appear to be working. The page is at http://www.asus.com/Search/

Is this a mistake I am making or is the form detecting the bot?

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new

#User Agent masking
agent.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Mozilla'

#This handles the url
page = agent.get('http://www.asus.com/Search/')
pp page

#Lock onto the search box
asus_form = page.form('aspnetForm')

#Prepare a search for our form
asus_form.q = 'TAICHI 21'

#Submit our form
button = asus_form.button_with(:value => "Button1")
page = agent.submit(asus_form, button)

#Output our Pretty Print to text file
pp page
File.open("results.txt","w") do |f|
  PP.pp(page,f)
end
```

Comment: If I look at the links listed for your `page`, there is one with the text "I confirm, please take me there.".

Comment: yes I noticed that, it doesn't appear when I render the page in a browser though

Comment: Found this in the Javascript code, I think it may be anti bot code.              $("#searchinput").keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $("#search-btn").click();
            /*var keyword = $("#searchinput").val();
            if (isApplicationPathSite()) window.location.href = '/' + getWebsite() + '/Search/Search?SearchKey=' + encodeURI(keyword);
            else window.location.href = '/Search/Search?SearchKey=' + encodeURI(keyword);
            return false;*/
        }
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a closer look at the results and I found your link in it. During my test I changed some things in the code, but I believe that doesn't really change anything. The last line finds your link.

```
agent = Mechanize.new

#User Agent masking
agent.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Mozilla'

#This handles the url
search = 'TAICHI 21'
page = agent.get("http://www.asus.com/Search/?SearchKey=#{search}")

#Output our Pretty Print to text file
File.open("results.txt","w") do |f|
  PP.pp(page.links.find_all{|l| l.text =~ /#{search}/i},f)
end
```

Comment: That is a good solution, now will need to find a way to do this with an array, will add this as a new question in a minute.